# Что такое поток вывода и ввода

Tags: c++

Не понимаю, что такое поток вывода и ввода? Поток представляю как отдельный процесс, который работает независимо от других процессов, но как это связано с `std::cout` и `std::cin`? Не могу это никак представить

Comment: Поток не выполнения, а поток символов/данных. Так проще понять?

Comment: Если грубо, то поток ввода - это место, откуда вам приходят данные. Часто это терминал. Но также может быть файл или сокет, например

Comment: К сожалению "переводчики" использую одно и то же слово "поток" и для **thread** (поток (можно было бы переводить как ***"нить"***) выполняемых машинных инструкций) и для **stream** (поток символов (байт) пересылаемых между программой и устройством ввода-вывода). Оличие же thread от process обычно заключается в том, что у процесса преполагается наличие независимого от других процессов адресного пространства, а у нескольких threads одного и того же процесса адресное пространство общее.

Answer (score 2):

> "stream" т.е. "поток" По сути, ввод/вывод в языке C++ реализован с помощью потоков. Абстрактно, поток — это последовательность символов, к которым можно получить доступ. Со временем поток может производить или потреблять потенциально неограниченные объемы данных.
> **Поток ввода** (или «входной поток») используется для хранения данных, полученных от источника данных: клавиатуры, файла, сети и т.д. Например, пользователь может нажать клавишу на клавиатуре в то время, когда программа не ожидает ввода. Вместо игнорирования нажатия клавиши, данные помещаются во входной поток, где затем ожидают ответа от программы.
> **Поток вывода** (или «выходной поток») используется для хранения данных, предоставляемых конкретному потребителю данных: монитору, файлу, принтеру и т.д. При записи данных на устройство вывода, это устройство может быть не готовым принять данные немедленно. Например, принтер все еще может прогреваться, когда программа уже записывает данные в выходной поток. Таким образом, данные будут находиться в потоке вывода до тех пор, пока принтер не начнет их использовать.
> Некоторые устройства, такие как файлы и сети, могут быть источниками как ввода, так и вывода данных.
> *Хорошая новость заключается в том, что программисту не нужно знать детали взаимодействия потоков с разными устройствами и источниками данных, ему нужно только научиться взаимодействовать с этими потоками для чтения и записи данных.*

[Источник](https://ravesli.com/urok-207-potoki-vvoda-vyvoda/?ysclid=lbuccgj08v640975614)

Comment: Если [текст написан не вами](https://ravesli.com/urok-207-potoki-vvoda-vyvoda/?ysclid=lbuccgj08v640975614), оформите его как цитату и добавьте ссылку на источник. Иначе это считается плагиатом (за который маленьким программистам массируют копчик).